# What's the Rails Way to pass data to controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, hidden-field

After getting some data from an API, I filtered the results and showed them on a view to et the user select which data he wants to save to the database. The user doesn't have to fill anything once all the data came from the API.

My question is: what's the best way/rails way to pass all this data to the controller?

Right now I'm using a form with hidden fields. It works but I was wondering if that's the best way.

Here's how my 'form_for' looks like:

```
<%= form_for (@new_photoset) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => not_imported_set.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :name, :value => not_imported_set.name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :thumb_url, :value => not_imported_set.url) %>
  <%= f.submit "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Make sure to add server-side validation as well since the values of hidden fields can be easily altered (e.g. the id field)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're on the right track, this is way you would normally do this in rails.